# Nx worskpace: import style file from library to app

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-library

I am working with Angular 12.
I created one library and one project.
In my library I have style (dark-theme.scss) file which I want to provide to the app.

I know from [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries) that I need to set assets to  ng-packagr. In nx workspace that is ng-package.json file in library root folder.

My ng-package.json look like:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/libs/my-lib",
  "assets": ["**/dark-theme.scss"],
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/index.ts"
  }
}
```

After library built I checked and my scss file is really on the path:

```
dist\libs\my-lib\dark-theme.scss
```

In my app I want to import that style into general app style (styles.scss):

```
@import "@my-lib/dark-theme.scss";
```

also tried:

```
@import "~@my-lib/dark-theme.scss";
```

When I tried to start app in Nx workspace I get error:

```
./apps/app-demo/src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @import "@my-lib/dark-theme.scss";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
```

All other files form the same library is successfully imported and works (modules, components, pipes...). I have only problem with this style/assets.

What is the proper way to do that ?

Comment: I also have this issue,I can import fonts but I can't import another CSS from inside a CSS file.Btw in your example you should update your project.json to the following syntax for assets
`        "assets": [
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "libs/assets/src/lib/themes",
            "output": "assets/themes"
          }
        ]`
Then your import in your CSS file should point to the public folder rather than the library. Something like 
`@import "../public/assets/themes/dark-theme.scss"; `